Convert PyQt5 and PyQt6
I am unable to convert my .py app into .exe. I tried using autopy2exe, but she tells me that I cannot do that because my application has two qt bindings:qt6 and qt5
Is there a later version that I need to install of auto-py
python.exe -m auto_py_to_exe


You can't use Qt 5 and 6 in the same program, autopy is just doing the right thing, which is to prevent a nonsensical build. Check your code and imports, and ensure that you only use one Qt version.
